# How to keep track of time in python without sleeping?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, sleep

I'm wondering how I can play a `.wav` file after some time has passed without using the `sleep` function.  Essentially, I was wondering if there is a way to **keep track of time** in Python, so that, after say 15 seconds has elapsed, I can play a sound without pausing my code.

```
# checks if I should play the sound or not and, sets the variable

def Tyler(self):
    if self.started == 1:
        if self.isTaiwan == 0:
            if self.myListNames[self.current_player_id / 3].lower() == "tyler":
                self.isTyler = 1
            else:
                self.isTyler = 0

self.Tyler()

if self.isTyler == 1:
    time.sleep(6)
    winsound.PlaySound("tyler.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

# This is where I would want to check to see 
# if some time has passed and the conditions haven't changed.
```

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method ?

Comment: @EricLevieil: Convert your comment to an answer so we can vote it up!  ;)

Comment: @EthanFurman I am still quite new here so feel free to correct me. To me, this question could be seen as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop and some people says you're not supposed to answer duplicates.

Comment: Go ahead and add your answer.  Sometimes different questions have the same answer, and this is one of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import time
def delay(secs):
    init_time = time()
    while time() < init_time+secs: pass
```

This won't use sleep but it is similar. Still uses time module